# Using Android Browser - Detecting page change

Tags: android, browser

I have an app that opens up the browser to a user given url. This should point to a certain login page that has no authentication. Is it possible to detect when the user clicks login to go to the member page that I can later parse for the HTML source? I'm just looking for some kind of on page change detection.

EDIT: I am now using WebView. Here's part of the new WebView activity class so far:

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("theurl(removed)"); // Removed url for StackOverflow
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('sid').value = 'name';"); // Supposed to autofill a particular input with id 'sid'
```

Trying to first change value of an input on the page, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to detect when the user clicks login to go to the member page that I can later parse for the HTML source?

Not using a standalone browser. That would be a security and privacy nightmare.

You are welcome to embed a `WebView` widget into your app, have the user log in via it, and then use JavaScript to grab data from any resulting pages.

Comment: I added my webview details. Please take a look at the edit! Can you first tell me what I am doing wrong with the inputs?

Comment: @MarkLyons: You are calling the second `loadUrl()` much too quickly, as the first `loadUrl()` is surely not yet done. `loadUrl()` is asynchronous.

Comment: So I should use some kind of function to wait until the page is fully loaded?

Comment: @MarkLyons: You can attach a `WebViewClient` to the `WebView` and override methods on it to find out about page events. `onPageFinished()` in theory would be what you want, but I have had mixed results, but it is certainly worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should open the url inside your app, simply by using a WebView with a custom WebViewClient:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
CustomWebViewClient webViewClient = new CustomWebViewClient();
myWebView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
```

You open your url with it :

```
myWebView.loadUrl("http://myurl.com");


  private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient { 

    @Override
    /**
     * I assume the url changes when the user clicks login, so parse the url and do the right stuff
     * I look for a fictitious sessionkey here
     */
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        try {
            String sessionKey = URLDecoder.decode(view.getUrl().split("session_key=")[1], "UTF-8");
            if ( sessionKey == 1337)
                {
                ...
                }                           
            }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    /**
     * Take control over the loaded url so the url is open in the current Webview and not with the default browser of Android
     */
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have started using webview before answers came. I think it would be more effective to do what I have now found is possible: I can load the url in webview, then change inputs based on info given previously in app. I have also read that it is possible to automatically 'click' the login button for them. Would it be more efficient to get the html source after the new page has finished loading (after login button onclick)?